# Removing parent without clicking on children

Tags: jquery, layer, children

I have layer A and layer B inside layer A

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/PhZhY/

Is it possible to remove layer A with jQuery function `remove()` clicking just on on layer A and not on layer B?

Comment: If you want B to remain, and I assume you do, then it can't be a child of A. You're going to have to position it on top of A but keep it as it's own separate entity.

Comment: Was question edited? I was pretty sure it was asked `B` to remain.

Comment: No it's not edited. Otherwise you colud see edit information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("body").on("click", ".a1", function(e) {
    if (this === e.target) $(this).remove();
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/PhZhY/1/

Comment: That removes b just like his does.

Comment: Yes but the point is not to trigger function by clicking on B

Comment: No, he wants B to stay intact, even if its parent gets deleted.

Comment: Pretty sure it was just a badly worded question. He already has a function that does exactly what this one does in his fiddle.

Comment: The title says: Removing parent without clicking on children

Comment: Read the question and his fiddle, relying on the title isn't much of a way of answering a question.

Comment: @RickCalder No, the function in fiddle has other functionality

Comment: *Is it possible to remove layer A with jQuery function remove() clicking just on on layer A and not on layer B?* Where do you see the point of leaving B untouched?

Comment: @RickCalder maybe in other browse the functionality works in other way?

Answer (score 2):

**If you want `.b1` to remain and delete just `.a1`**

```
$('.a1').live('click',function() {
     $(".b1", this).unwrap();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PhZhY/3/

You can remove that div even if you don't know any child element:

```
$('.a1').live('click',function() {
     $(".a1 :first-child").unwrap();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PhZhY/5/

**If you want to remove `.a1` div if it's not clicked within `.b2` this is what you need:**

```
$('.a1').live('click',function() {
     $(".a1 :first-child").unwrap();
});

$('.b1').live('click',function() {
 throw "stop execution";
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PhZhY/6/

According to @Rick Calder's comment:
If you want you can use `.addClass()` to change class or `.removeClass()` to remove class.

Comment: better answer, just needs to adjust class to keep B in position.

Comment: Even though (for some reason) it leaves B, the event works both clicking A and B, which is invalid due to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I read the question:

If you click on `.b1`, nothing should happen. If you click on `.a1` it should be removed.

If that's the intent, here's the jQuery:

```
$('.b1').click( function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('.a1').click( function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iserij/1/edit). Note: css, html shamelessly stolen from @Vision's jsFiddle